# using $.each to iterate over an array of objects - problems with regular expression

Tags: jquery

I have been using the `$.each` function and some templating so that I can effectively populate/replace my HTML string stored in the `temp` variable with the `title` and `thumbnail` property of the objects stored in the `content` array.

So for example within the callback function of `$.each` a regular expression finds the `{{title}}`, it will replace `{{title}}` with the contents of `obj.title`, so that we essentially replace it with the string 'Speak of the devil and he shall appear' which is the title property of the object which is iterated over.

The problem I have found is that when I come to append this HTML string (`temp variable`) to the body. My `img` HTML tag has been outputted in the wrong way and the contents of `obj.title` are creating undesired attributes in my `img` tag

HTML outputted:

```
<h2> Speak of the devil and he shall appear </h2>
<img appear="" shall="" he="" and="" devil="" the="" of="" alt="Speak" src="images/bane.jpg">
```

Here is my template:

```
<script id="blogTemplate" type="chris/template">
    <h2> {{title}} </h2>
    <img src={{thumbnail}} alt={{title}}>
</script>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
(function() {

        var content = [
            {
                title: 'Speak of the devil and he shall appear',   
                thumbnail: 'images/bane.jpg',
            },

            {
                title: 'Me the joker',   
                thumbnail: 'images/Joker.jpg',
            }
        ];

            var template = $.trim( $('#blogTemplate').html() );

        $.each( content, function( index, obj ) {  

            var temp = template.replace( /{{title}}/ig, obj.title )
                               .replace( /{{thumbnail}}/ig, obj.thumbnail );
            console.log(temp);

            $('body').append(temp);
        });

    })();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify your template to include quotes around the attributes.

```
<script id="blogTemplate" type="chris/template">
    <h2> {{title}} </h2>
    <img src="{{thumbnail}}" alt="{{title}}">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advice you to take a look at Handlebars: http://handlebarsjs.com/. You are almost doing the same but with handlebars you have much more support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `{` and `}` characters in your regex, i.e.

```
template.replace(/\{\{title\}\}/ig, obj.title)
```

Unescaped, `{n}` will match exactly `n` occurrences of the previous character. Check out the [Regex guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more info.